# is there any way of getting the text from a label in a grid with just the row and column in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am building an eight puzzle using Tkinter, I have managed to generate the 3x3 grid.

```
import random

from tkinter import *

puzzle  = Tk()
puzzle.title("Eight Puzzle")
frame = Frame(puzzle)

number = 8

for i in range (0,3):
    for a in range (0,3):
        
        if number == 0:
            Label (frame, text = "").grid(row=i, column=a)
        else:
            Label (frame, text = number).grid(row=i, column=a)
        number= number -1

frame.pack()
```

but now I need a way of getting the values from certain spaces in the grid with their row and column, to swap when the user says so and also to shuffle the grid.

Comment: `frame.grid_slaves(row, column)` will return a list of widgets in that position. iterate through it. eg: `frame.grid_slaves(0, 0)[0]['text']`

Comment: also You can pack the frame immediately You don't have to append stuff to it and then pack it You can just pack it right after initializing and the other stuff will be added later.

Comment: @Matiiss ok thanks for that advice.

Comment: @JacksonPro thanks i will try that.